# How to using Dagster recommended structure with Docker/ECS

Tags: grpc, dagster

Dagster recommends structuring your project list [this](https://docs.dagster.io/guides/dagster/recommended-project-structure):

```
project_fully_featured
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── dbt_project
├── project_fully_featured
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── activity_analytics
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── activity_forecast.py
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── id_range_for_time.py
│   │   │   └── items.py
│   │   └── recommender
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── comment_stories.py
│   │       ├── recommender_model.py
│   │       ├── user_story_matrix.py
│   │       └── user_top_recommended_stories.py
│   ├── jobs.py
│   ├── partitions.py
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── common_bucket_s3_pickle_io_manager.py
│   │   ├── duckdb_parquet_io_manager.py
│   │   ├── hn_resource.py
│   │   ├── parquet_io_manager.py
│   │   ├── partition_bounds.py
│   │   └── snowflake_io_manager.py
│   ├── sensors
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── hn_tables_updated_sensor.py
│   │   └── slack_on_failure_sensor.py
│   └── utils
├── project_fully_featured_tests
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tox.ini
```

I need to do this and run it from docker/ AWS ECS. I am able to get this project working in Docker/ECS: https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/tree/master/examples/deploy_docker

But I don't know how to convert the deploy_docker example to use the recommended code structure where there is no repo.py, and all assets are in a directory called assets.

Can someone recommend how this might be done?

Comment: Is the obstacle for you to configure the Dockerfile correctly to detect all the files?